# can every object be represented mathematically?

Tags: 3d, mathematical-modeling, curves

I was just wondering if all 2D/3D objects/images/shapes could be represented by equations. For example, [SpongeBob 2D curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=draw%20spongebob%20curve&a=*C.spongebob%20curve-_*PopularCurveClass-) and many more. How should I approach, as in, some theories that already exist? Perhaps, It would be of a great help if I get to hear your incredibly usable points of view!

The REAL QUESTION is:

> **how can I develop equation all descriptions of some pictures I have in mind?**

Comment: The first question is impossibly vague, but the second question makes me think your real question is "how can I develop equation all descriptions of some pictures I have in mind?" which is a better question. You might want to rewrite to emphasize that.

Comment: you have to formalize (mathematically) what means "represented by equations". and I didn't get what was the general form of their "mr krab's equation", $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ look like piecewise trigonometric polynomials, thus related to the trigonometric interpolation  passing through some set of points $x_i,y_i$ ?

Comment: In two dimensions, open a drawing program like Adobe Illustrator, overlay an image, and create spline curves that outline the shapes in the image that interest you.  (The program supports, I think, only curves given by equations of particular forms that have been proven to be especially useful for this purpose.)  The technology has existed for decades.  3D is harder but people have been thinking e.g. about shape from shading (reconstructing a 3D shape from photographs) since the 1970s.  Look for info on 3D modeling, 3D scanners, and the like.

Comment: I plan to plot data-points of a 'leaf' on a graph with simple intersection of $y = \log x+1$ and $y = \log x^2$ , and by the intersection, I had a beautiful curve of leaf (you may try! :D) ; but now it is a set of equations, how can I represent this as a single curve, perhaps, I form or a methodology for combining the two equations.